# UserControl MouseButtonEventHandler Microsoft Surface Application

Tags: wpf, user-controls, pixelsense, mouseleftbuttondown

I have just start working with Microsoft Surface.I have designed a `UserControl` in Blend 4. And implemented a simple `DrapDrop` event over the `UserControl`.  It works fine. The problem is, when i click over the `UserControl`, `UserControl` just jumps to another location.
For dragdrop, i have use this code
[How to drag a UserControl inside a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495408/how-to-drag-a-usercontrol-inside-a-canvas)

The only design difference is, my `UserControl` is inside the Grid. And in this example, it is implemented inside a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

To move things around the screen on `Surface`, you want to use the `ScatterView` control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In ScatterView, it randomly scatter the items over the Canvas. I have arranged controls in a specific order. Later i want users to drag them smoothly over the screen. If i am missing something in ScatterView, let me know.

Comment: you can override the randomness by explicitly setting the Center property of each ScattervViewItem before you add them to the ScatterView.Items collection

Comment: @Adeel, no problem.  please click the checkmark next to any answers on this site that help you