# make line that connects two objects in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, line, connect

how can I connect these entity boxes?

[image]

the boxes are created by clicking a button and they can be dragged. Now I want to connect them with a line or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty implementation:

the class that represents the connection:

```
public partial class Connection
{
    public MyBox Box1 { get; set; }
    public MyBox Box2 { get; set; }
    public Line Line { get; set; }
}
```

To create a new connection I've used a basic form: name of source, destination and a button:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3">
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding From,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBlock Text=" ----> " />
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding To,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Content="Connect" Click="Button_Click_2" />
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the handler:

```
public string From { get; set; }
public string To { get; set; }

private IList<Connection> connections = new List<Connection>();
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyBox box1 = boxes.Single(b => b.Header == From);
    MyBox box2 = boxes.Single(b => b.Header == To);

    Connection conn = new Connection { Box1 = box1, Box2 = box2, Line = new Line { StrokeThickness = 1, Stroke = Brushes.Black } };
    connections.Add(conn);

    RefreshLinesPositions();

    panel.Children.Add(conn.Line);
}
```

And the RefreshLinesPositions code:

```
private void RefreshLinesPositions()
{
    foreach (Connection conn in connections)
    {
        Point p1 = conn.Box1.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), panel);
        Point p2 = conn.Box2.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), panel);

        double t1 = p1.Y;
        double b1 = p1.Y + conn.Box1.ActualHeight;
        double l1 = p1.X;
        double r1 = p1.X + conn.Box1.ActualWidth;

        double t2 = p2.Y;
        double b2 = p2.Y + conn.Box2.ActualHeight;
        double l2 = p2.X;
        double r2 = p2.X + conn.Box2.ActualWidth;

        if (r1 < l2)
        {
            conn.Line.X1 = r1;
            conn.Line.Y1 = t1 + (b1 - t1) / 2;
            conn.Line.X2 = l2;
            conn.Line.Y2 = t2 + (b2 - t2) / 2;

            conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (r2 < l1)
        {
            conn.Line.X1 = r2;
            conn.Line.Y1 = t2 + (b2 - t2) / 2;
            conn.Line.X2 = l1;
            conn.Line.Y2 = t1 + (b1 - t1) / 2;

            conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (b1 < t2)
        {
            conn.Line.X1 = l1 + (r1 - l1) / 2;
            conn.Line.Y1 = b1;
            conn.Line.X2 = l2 + (r2 - l2) / 2;
            conn.Line.Y2 = t2;

            conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (b2 < t1)
        {
            conn.Line.X1 = l1 + (r1 - l1) / 2;
            conn.Line.Y1 = t1;
            conn.Line.X2 = l2 + (r2 - l2) / 2;
            conn.Line.Y2 = b2;

            conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Line.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

And you call RefreshLinesPositions whenever a box is moved:

```
private void Box_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (draggedBox != null)
    {
        ...

        RefreshLinesPositions();
    }
}
```

**EDIT: for the nodes**

The new *RefreshLinesPosition* version:

```
private void RefreshLinesPositions()
{
    foreach (Connection conn in connections)
    {
        Point p1 = conn.Box1.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), panel);
        Point p2 = conn.Box2.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), panel);

        double t1 = p1.Y;
        double b1 = p1.Y + conn.Box1.ActualHeight;
        double l1 = p1.X;
        double r1 = p1.X + conn.Box1.ActualWidth;

        double t2 = p2.Y;
        double b2 = p2.Y + conn.Box2.ActualHeight;
        double l2 = p2.X;
        double r2 = p2.X + conn.Box2.ActualWidth;

        if (r1 < l2)
        {
            conn.Line.X1 = r1;
            conn.Line.Y1 = t1 + (b1 - t1) / 2;
            conn.Line.X2 = l2;
            conn.Line.Y2 = t2 + (b2 - t2) / 2;

            conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            conn.Node1.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(r1, t1 + (b1 - t1) / 2);
            conn.Node2.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(l2 - conn.Node2.Text.ActualWidth, t2 + (b2 - t2) / 2);
        }
        else if (r2 < l1)
        {
            conn.Line.X1 = l1;
            conn.Line.Y1 = t1 + (b1 - t1) / 2;
            conn.Line.X2 = r2;
            conn.Line.Y2 = t2 + (b2 - t2) / 2;

            conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            conn.Node1.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(l1 - conn.Node1.Text.ActualWidth, t1 + (b1 - t1) / 2);
            conn.Node2.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(r2, t2 + (b2 - t2) / 2);
        }
        else if (b1 < t2)
        {
            conn.Line.X1 = l1 + (r1 - l1) / 2;
            conn.Line.Y1 = b1;
            conn.Line.X2 = l2 + (r2 - l2) / 2;
            conn.Line.Y2 = t2;

            conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            conn.Node1.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(l1 + (r1 - l1) / 2, b1);
            conn.Node2.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(l2 + (r2 - l2) / 2, t2 - conn.Node2.Text.ActualHeight);
        }
        else if (b2 < t1)
        {
            conn.Line.X1 = l1 + (r1 - l1) / 2;
            conn.Line.Y1 = t1;
            conn.Line.X2 = l2 + (r2 - l2) / 2;
            conn.Line.Y2 = b2;

            conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            conn.Node1.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(l1 + (r1 - l1) / 2, t1 - conn.Node1.Text.ActualHeight);
            conn.Node2.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(l2 + (r2 - l2) / 2, b2);
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Line.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

The new event handler:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyBox box1 = boxes.Single(b => b.Header == From);
    MyBox box2 = boxes.Single(b => b.Header == To);

    Connection conn = new Connection
    {
        Box1 = box1,
        Box2 = box2,
        Line = new Line { StrokeThickness = 1, Stroke = Brushes.Black },
        Node1 = new Node { Text = new TextBox() },
        Node2 = new Node { Text = new TextBox() }
    };
    connections.Add(conn);

    panel.Children.Add(conn.Line);

    panel.Children.Add(conn.Node1.Text);
    panel.Children.Add(conn.Node2.Text);

    RefreshLinesPositions();
}
```

I've used this for representing nodes:

```
public partial class Node
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public TextBox Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i'm getting an error on the "From" and "To", it says it doesnt exist

Comment: i click on connect, but nothing happens, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Try to debug and particularly if you reach one of the "conn.Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;"

Comment: when i click on connect, it crashes and appears this error: "InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code - Sequence contains no matching element"

Comment: The code searches for boxes by header name: if you have a box with header "a" and another with "b" then ensure that *From* is "a" and *To* is "b".

Comment: When you debug and break at the start of Button_Click_2 what are the values of *From* and *To*?

Comment: in output there is no errors, it only gives an error when i click connect as i mentioned above

Comment: Do you bind other properties too? If no check the DataContext, should be the MainWindow. Otherwise, if you don't manage to fix the binding, simply give a name to the TextBoxes and use their Text property directly. :)

Comment: can you do me somethig like that but for the nodes? to get the nodes always close to the connection :)

Comment: i'm getting errors in the translatetransform's "conn.Node1.Text.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(r1, t1 + (b1 - t1) / 2);" it says that a TranslateTransform does not contain a constructor that takes two arguments

Comment: @LuisAmaro: SL again :( Try `new TranslateTransform{ X = r1, Y = t1 + (b1 - t1) / 2) }`

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to get the position of each boxes ;
2. Draw a `Path` between the boxes ;
3. Redraw on boxes drag/drop...

Simple sample with two `Rectangle` :

**XAML :**

```
<Canvas x:Name="Root">
    <Rectangle
        x:Name="rect1"
        Fill="Aqua"
        Width="20"
        Height="20"
        Canvas.Left="24"
        Canvas.Top="44" />
    <Rectangle
        x:Name="rect2"
        Fill="Red"
        Width="20"
        Height="20"
        Canvas.Left="119"
        Canvas.Top="73" />
</Canvas>
```

**C# :**

```
ConnectBoxes(Root, rect1, rect2);
....

public void ConnectBoxes(Canvas container, Rectangle boxeSrc, Rectangle boxeDest)
{
    var transform1 = boxeSrc.TransformToVisual(container);
    var transform2 = boxeDest.TransformToVisual(container);

    var lineGeometry = new LineGeometry()
    {
        StartPoint = transform1.Transform(
            new Point(boxeSrc.ActualWidth / 2, boxeSrc.ActualHeight / 2.0)
        ),
        EndPoint = transform2.Transform(
            new Point(boxeDest.ActualWidth / 2.0, boxeDest.ActualHeight / 2.0)
        )
    };
    container.Children.Add(new Path()
    {
        Data = lineGeometry,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown),
        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Brown),

    });
}
```

Comment: this example is good, but how can I do this without premade objects? i'm guessing the better way to do the lines is by clicking a button which permits to draw a line from one object to another....

this example on the link is perfect but it's on wpf and I can't put this on my project :/ http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/wpf-draggable-objects-and-simple-shape-connectors/

Comment: do you know how to make the path to adjust with the rectangles when dragging?