# Moving Control over a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a small WPF application which uses a `ScrollViewer` to show an `Image` in a `Window`.
I have generated the window and all his relative code (I will show it if needed but I think is not usefull for the point of this question) programmatically.

The question/ how to is the following. I have to show/hide (pressing a button) a control (basically a `InkCanvas`) over the image contained in the `ScrollViewer`. Except the part oh show/hide is pretty simple to use the button event) which is the best way to add a control (and which type of control/container) at the Window forcing him to be over the ScrollViewer and then be able to **move around dragging it**?

I'm relatively new to WPF I used a lot of WinForms (I can do this in WinForms but WPF is a new world for me).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the container you should use a `Grid` which will center and put on top of each other the controls in a same cell.

As for drag and drop if you want to implement it yourself I've provided a minimal implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17014906/145757

Otherwise you can use the `MouseDragElementBehavior` behavior provided by **Blend**.

Here is a tutorial that demonstrates its usage from **Blend** itself: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/expression-blend-4-behaviors/

But you can use it without Blend by importing the Blend libraries and using it from your XAML with something like:

```
<InkCanvas ...>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <blendbehaviors:MouseDragElementBehavior />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</InkCanvas>
```

with `interactivity` and `blendbehaviors` being mapped to the Blend namespaces.

Comment: I had to Answer my question, the post was too long for a direct comment.