# WPF Run-Time Move and Resize Control on Canvas Jittery and Jerky and Flickering

Tags: drag-and-drop, resize, controls, flicker, doublebuffered

To move and resize a custom control on a Canvas in run-time in a WPF project, I'm using the code here: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2017/05/move-resize-multiple-rectangles-wpf-c/ and here: [How to drag a UserControl inside a Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495408/how-to-drag-a-usercontrol-inside-a-canvas)

However, the control doesn't move smoothly, it's jerky and jittery - kind of like in the days before WPF when we would turn on double-buffering (which I understand is unnecessary in WPF).  Any ideas how to make the move/resize smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using this implementation, instead:  https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/709121/Move-and-Resize-Controls-on-a-Form-at-Runtime-With