# WPF bind Line Point(x,y) to a stackpanel position Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have 2 StackPanel, which can be move around inside a canvas. and I want the line to re-drawn when I drag one of the StackPanel. How do I properly bind the line points(X1,Y1,X2,Y2) between the two StackPanel? This is how I did right now :

```
Line line = new Line();
line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
line.StrokeThickness = 1.5;

Binding ogX = new Binding();
ogX.Source = originalStackPanel.TransformToAncestor(qbw).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).X;

Binding ogY = new Binding();
ogY.Source = originaStackPanel.TransformToAncestor(qbw).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).Y;

Binding tgX = new Binding();
tgX.Source = targetStackPanel.TransformToAncestor(qbw).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).X;

Binding tgY = new Binding();
tgY.Source = targetStackPanel.TransformToAncestor(qbw).Transform(new Point(0, 0)).Y;

line.SetBinding(Line.X1Property, ogX);
line.SetBinding(Line.Y1Property, ogY);
line.SetBinding(Line.X2Property, tgX);
line.SetBinding(Line.Y2Property, tgY);
```

and the line only draw once. It won't change dynamically. So how is the correct way to bind line points properly?

[image]

added photos for giving 'clear pictures' of the problem :v. so basically the lines is drawn when i drag one of those black boxes, and drop to another black boxes, and a line is drawn, but the panel can move around, so the lines have to re-drawn.

Comment: Besides that your current approach can't work (because there is no Binding source property with change notification), it is unclear how it is supposed to work. In order to get a useful answer, you should explain the desired behaviour. How exactly should the line connect the two panels? How are the panels positioned inside the Canvas, e.g. by Canvas.Left/Top or by a transform? You should certainly have a view model with properties for all related positions.

Comment: okay, actually the stackpanel is inside a user control, and i followed the drag code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495408/how-to-drag-a-usercontrol-inside-a-canvas. from the code it should be using transform, i assume?. as for how exactly should the line connect the two panel, the user click on of the panels, and drag to the second panel, and the line is drawn.

Comment: Sorry, I'm behind a firewall and not able to look at your image.